# Highcharts update breaks previous layout

Tags: javascript, web, graph, highcharts

I was using highcharts 4.0.4 and after the update to highcharts 4.2.3 the result is:

[image: Highcharts graph overlay]

How do one solve this?

**EDIT**
It is supposed to be like:

[image: Highcharts graph don't overlay]

**EDIT 2**
Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mluis/zupyb7o6/3/).

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {

    xAxis: {
     type: 'datetime'
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
        type: 'line'
    }],
    chart: {
      renderTo: 'container',
      reflow: false,
      zoomType: 'x'
    },
    legend: {
        align: 'bottom',
        // verticalAlign: 'bottom',
        // layout: 'vertical',
        layout: 'horizontal'
      },
    title: {
      text: 'Explorer'
    },

});
```

```css
#container {
    min-width: 300px;
    max-width: 800px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 1em auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/offline-exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Please replicate your example as live demo on the jsfiddle.net

Comment: You haven't shown us what it is supposed to look like, and you haven't shown us your code. We can't help if you don't provide the information.

Comment: It is supposed the legend be below the graph. I will provide a jsfiddle asap also.

Comment: Would you comment please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by removing

> align: 'bottom'